# Cannot popup Android virtual keyboard from TextField

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am using `Qt 5.5.1 Opensource` on `Ubuntu 14.40 LTS 64bit` and working on app for `Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1` running `Android 4.2.2`. and I have following testing `TextField`:

```
TextField
{
    width: 384
    height: 128

    placeholderText: qsTr("Android Virtual Keyboard does not pop up")

    focus: true

    onTextChanged:
    {
        print("Text changed");
    }   // onTextChanged

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
            print("clicked");
            forceActiveFocus(Qt.MouseFocusReason);
            Qt.inputMethod.show();
        }   // onClicked
    }   // MouseArea
}   // TextField
```

Now, once the focus is of this component is gained - the user selects it on touch screen, message *"clicked"* is printed on debug console, which is ok, but `Android keyboard` is not showed so the user cannot enter anytext into it.

Why?

and

Does someone has better experience using `TextEdit` or even `TextArea`, I have personally preferred `TextField` so far because of `TextField`'s `placeholderText`  property? I use several `TextField` components for entering database connection setup.

Comment: You should force active focus on textfield, i.e. `<id>.forceActiveFocus()`, here you are forcing the focus on the `MouseArea` itself. But really, why using a `MouseArea` here? It's totally useless since `TextField` already triggers the keyboard.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo ok, good guideline, but, where then I should put `forceActiveFocus()` after I omit `MouseArea`?

Comment: Why would you use `forceActiveFocus`? That's the question. :) Do you have a layered set of `MouseArea`s? Just put them z-*under* the `TextField`s so that active focus is gained by the latter ones.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078973/qt-textfield-is-not-invoking-the-keyboard-when-launched-on-android-device/45755411#45755411](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078973/qt-textfield-is-not-invoking-the-keyboard-when-launched-on-android-device/45755411#45755411)